# How do I reverse 0 and 1 using LabelEncoder?

Tags: python

LabelEncoder automatically categorize different classes based on alphabetical order, so how do I reverse it?

[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoGdI.png)

Answer (score 0):

### If `y` is an array:

You can inverse the input

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np
y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])

LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)
# array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])

LabelEncoder().fit_transform(-y)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

### If `y` is a list:

You can inverse the output.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
y = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)
# array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])

1 - LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

### Yapa

**array** is a class of numpy, so, when you want to make any transformation to this type of object, look for numpy array transformation.